# DFA minimazation (dead state)

Tags: finite-automata

I was trying to minimize given DFA:

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -> 1 | 4 | 2 |
| F 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 |
| F 4 | 1 | 1 |

I've watched few videos about solving this problem and decided to use the equivalance method.
While doing it I've come to the solution below:

- 0 Equivalance: {1,3} {2,4}
- 1 Equivalance: {1} {3} {2,4}

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -> 1 | 2,4 | 2,4 |
| F 2,4 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2,4 |

which translates into the following graph:

[image]

State 3 looks dead to me. Should I even draw it if the solution is correct? What would be the point of this state?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's inaccessable; you don't need it.